# Redirect in AngularJS does not work for some reason

Tags: angularjs

Please advise how can I make a redirect in AngularJS?
I tried to use several options:

```
$location.path('/TemplateView');
```

When I do this, I can see some get request but the page remains the same.

I also tried also: `$scope.$state...` but Angular does not recognize it.

Googling didn't help.

Comment: show some code or demo to reproduce the problem so that some one can help

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with your code ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `$location.path()` you have to do 3 things:

Inject ngRoute module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Define a route:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/TemplateView', {
                controller: 'TemplateCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'templates/index.html'
            });
    }]);
```

Make a redirect in the controller (assuming you inject `$location` to your controller)

```
$location.path('/TemplateView');
```

**Note:**
Changing the route/template does not necessarily mean you have to see GET request or any other request. AngularJS is a single page framework, so if your browser has already downloaded all partials, changing views/controllers will not make any calls to the servers (just manipulate with local content, your browser already downloaded).

Comment: I've done all the 3 parts and as I wrote it does not work: I can see it makes a get request but the View remains the same